# Python:Problema While: Print n veces, si n esta en un rango de valor entre 0 y 5

Tags: python-3.x, while

Tengo que hacer en python, y solo con while's, el siguiente problema:
Introducir un numero, este será el numero de veces que se printee hello world.
Si el numero no esta entre 0 y 5 vuelve a preguntar un numero hasta que este entre un valor entre 0 y 5.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Introduzco un valor mas grande de 5 y me vuelve a preguntar, pero solo dos veces y da por finalizado el programa. Entiendo que tengo que anidar los dos while.

Por el momento tengo esto

```
numero=int(input("num between 0 and 5, print num times hello world"))
i=0
while numero < 6:
    while i < numero:
        print ("Hola mundo")
        i=i+1
numero=int(input("num between 0 and 5, print num times hello world"))
```

Comment: Y que quieres saber?

Comment: que estoy haciendo mal, porque me muestra dos veces la pregunta ( en el caso de que sea mas grande de 5) y da por finalizado el programa :/

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade  eso que has puesto para que la gente lo pueda saber.

Comment: Editado, disculpas de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema conceptual y de sintaxis y me atrevería quizás a decir dudosamente pedagógico.

El primer while nunca va a ejecutarse con tu condición de 0-5 porque evalúas que se ejecute si el numero es mayor que 5.

El segundo while igual, porque si consigues pasar el primero, la siguiente condición tampoco se cumple porque `i` es 0 y numero es más grande que 5.

Por terminar el segundo `input()` no te va a hacer nada porque es el ultimo comando del programa y pongas lo que pongas termina la ejecución y se cierra el proceso

Con esto que te he dicho inténtalo otra vez y si tienes más dudas pregunta. Un saludo

EDIT:
Esta seria "una" de tantas formas de hacerlo más acorde a la sintaxis de python por poner un ejemplo más didáctico, sin necesidad de while loops que pueden dar más dolores de cabeza que soluciones.

```
while True:
    numero = int(input("Num between 1 and 5, print num times hello world: "))
    if 0 < numero <= 5:
        for _ in range(numero):
            print("Hello world")
        break
```

El `while` es para que te repita el input hasta que el bucle no lo rompas con el `break`.
Cada bucle te pide un numero, y se evalúa con `if` que sea mayor que 0 (no tiene sentido imprimir Hello world 0 veces) o igual o menor que 5.
Si se cumple la condición se crea otro bucle que se repite `numero` veces con `range(numero)` imprimiendo Hello world cada vez.
Al final de ese bucle se rompe el `while True` con break y se termina el proceso.
La variable `_` es anonima, es decir, no se pretende usar para nada, pero la sintaxis del bucle for necesita al menos una variable por necesidad (Por costumbre se usa _ si no se usa pero puede llamarse i, lola, variable, pepito o lo que quieras)

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. No tenia que anidar los while's, era inposible que fuera asi. Como bien apuntas tenemos un profesorado de dudoso valor pedagógico. Y el material tampoco tiene pinta de que nos vaya a ayudar mucho. Pico y pala. Muchas gracias con tus apuntes he conseguido deducir la solución. Me sobrecoje el apoyo que se puede vivir en esta comunidad

Comment: Si ya lo has solucionado puedes incluir tu solución como respuesta para futuros usuarios que tengan los mismos problemas. También puedes aceptar la respuesta de Jose (pulsando el tick verde) si te ha servido (o incluso la tuya cuando la subas)

Answer (score 1):

Te daré un par de pistas para enfocar el problema, puesto que Jose Rodríguez ya te ha dicho cuales son los problemas en tu código.

- En primer lugar necesitas que se introduzca un número (hecho).
- En segundo lugar necesitas un bucle que esté pidiendo un número nuevo
  **mientras** que el número no esté entre  0 y 5.
- Resuelto esto necesitas un bucle nuevo (diferente) que vaya
  imprimiendo `'hola mundo'` y por ejemplo restando 1 a `número` **mientras**
  `número` no valga 0 (hay varias maneras de hacerlo, esta sería una).

**Solución**

Puesto que ya has subido tu solución al problema, añado la que había probado y que como te digo en los comentarios, tiene en cuenta también números negativos y evita crear una nueva variable (`i` en tu código)

```
numero=int(input("num between 0 and 5, print num times hello world"))

while numero > 5 or numero < 0:
    numero=int(input("num between 0 and 5, print num times hello world"))

while numero != 0:
    print ("Hola mundo")
    i-=1
```

Comment: Creía que lo tenia bien y no! me aceptaba el caso de valor 6 porque habia puesto mas el primer while. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Solución al problema planteado:

```
numero=int(input("num between 0 and 5, print num times hello world"))

while numero > 5:
    numero=int(input("num between 0 and 5, print num times hello world"))

i=0
while i < numero:
    print ("Hola mundo")
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Buena Solución Isaac, +1 por compartirla. Como te decía hay varias maneras de hacerlo. si en el segundo bucle usas while numero != 0: y vas restando 1 a numero, te evitas crear otra variable más (i). Por otro lado no has tenido en cuenta si el numero es negativo, prueba por ejemplo con while numero > 5 or numero < 0:

Comment: Vaya es cierto no conte con la posibilidad de que el usuario pueda introducir negativos. El ejemplo que propones lo he usado en otro while. Esto es un tema aparte que no se si puedo comentar pero, estoy muy decepcionado con la calidad pedagógica del profesorado. A estas horas mis compañeros de clase todavía estaban bajo la misma premisa de que eran dos while's anidados y evidentemente no. Lo que me preocupa es la cuota de frustración a la que nos exponen para un ejercicio de dificultad evidentemente moderada. Muchas gracias por todas las correcciones de uso de stack overflow soy nuevo ^^U